# how to rebuild dialog Widget on changing bool variable state?

Tags: flutter

im trying to submit form on Dialog and i have a DateTimePicker button and need to make a validation on it also before submitting , what i want to do is showing a text error in case no date picked by changing my own variable "isValid" to false but the UI is not updating , i have to close the dialog and reopen it to see the error text even though i wrapped my column with a StatefulBuilder

[my dialog photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjTT.png)

here is my code

```
StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
                return isValid == false
                    ? Column(
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                 DateTimePicker(context)
                                    .then((value) => setState(() {
                                          _appointmentDateTime = value;
                                        }));
                              },
                              child: Text(getTimeDate())),
                          Text(
                            'error',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.red, fontSize: 10),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                DateTimePicker(context)
                                    .then((value) => setState(() {
                                          _appointmentDateTime = value;
                                        }));
                              },
                              child: Text(getTimeDate())),
                        ],
                      );
              })
```

Validating form + toggling the isValid Value is working fine

```
OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate() &&
                          _appointmentDateTime != null) {
                        String date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')
                            .format(_appointmentDateTime);
                        var appointment = Appointment(
                            patientName: widget.patient.name,
                            date: date,
                            hospital: _hospitalController.text,
                        await FirebaseApi.addPatientAppointment(
                            widget.patient.id, appointment);
                        print('Appointment Created ');
                        _formKey.currentState.reset();
                        setState(() {
                          translator = null;
                          _appointmentDateTime = null;
                        });
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } 

                            else {
                            setState(() {
                              isValid = !isValid;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Add Appointment')),
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but how this could help with showing and hiding the error text under "Date Button" ? according to the bool isValid Value when pressing on the "Add Appointment" Button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get confusing when writing the code like this when dealing with Dialogs. The `setState` you are using in the `OutlinedButton` is not the same as the `setState` used in the `StatefulBuilder`. You need to enclose your OutlinedButton inside the `StatefulBuilder` too. If you ever use a `StatefulBuilder` inside a stateful widget, it is better to use a different name like e.g setDialogState.

It is even better to create a separate stateful widget class just for your Dialog contents and pass the formKey and anything else than using a `StatefulBuilder` in this case to avoid confusion.